# How to POST an ArrayList with a String at the same time in RETROFIT?

Tags: java, android, post, retrofit

I'm trying to post an ArrayList and a String value in Retrofit. How can I send them at the same post ? 
I've tried this but it didn't work.
Thank you.

Etiket_post.java

```
@POST("/api/r_etiket")
Call<Result> post_etiket(@Body List< EtiketItem_List> items, @Body String FileNo);
```

Print_Screen.java

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("myURL")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build();
Etiket_Post etiket_post = retrofit.create(Etiket_Post.class);
String FileNo = FileId;
ArrayList<EtiketItem_List> items = new ArrayList<>();
for (int e = 0; e < okutulan_list.size(); e++) {
    items.add(new EtiketItem_List(
        okutulan_list.get(e).STOK_KODU,
        okutulan_list.get(e).STOK_ADI,
        okutulan_list.get(e).OlcuBrim,
        okutulan_list.get(e).STHAR_GCMIK));
}
Call<Result> call = etiket_post.post_etiket(items, FileNo);
call.enqueue(new Callback<Result>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<Result> call, Response<Result> response) {
        Toast.makeText(Print_Screen.this, response.body().result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<Result> call, Throwable t) {
        Toast.makeText(Print_Screen.this, t.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You can send data in raw format using Retrofit2 like this.

```
    {
  "String1" :"anyString",
  "arrayList":[
       {
        "A":"Appple",
        "B":"ball"
    }
  ]
```

}

> modelClass example

```
 @SerializedName("user_id")
@Expose
private String user_id;

@SerializedName("product")
@Expose
List<OneProductModel> oneProductModels;


public CartPost(String user_id, List<OneProductModel> oneProductModels) {
    this.user_id = user_id;
    this.oneProductModels = oneProductModels;
}

@POST("/api/r_etiket")
Call<Result> post_etiket(@Body modelClass);
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! it works ^^ I didn't think of that. This way easy and usefull.

Comment: Cool bro happy to help you